# export fullcalendar to google calendar, ical, etc

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Is it possible to export FullCalendar events into google calendar or ical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [http://michalkorecki.com/content/introducing-json-xml-jquery-plugin](https://web.archive.org/web/20120415040917/http://michalkorecki.com/content/introducing-json-xml-jquery-plugin)

You can then export the event objects from FullCalendar to XML for use with Google Calendar.

Comment: The link is dead so this answer doesn't answer anything.

Comment: @RyanConrad that's a little bit harsh... he did answer in April 2011 and you visited the page in November 2012... a good 19 months later.... He can't be expected to constantly check the links in all his answers to make sure they are still active.

Comment: @vletech that's why you shouldn't use links to answer a question. This answer doesn't help anyone. putting what needs to be done in the answer would have been a better option.

Comment: @RyanConrad That is a good point... He could have added the information from the link as well as the original reference.

Comment: @Redwall I fixed the link

Comment: @mgttlinger cheers thanks for updating link...will take a look and see if I can make sense of it..