# Does fullcalendar support exporting to Google Calendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar on my website now and I'll need to be able to export it to Google Calendar. I know that fetching events from Google Calendar is possible with (fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar) but the converse doesn't seem to be that easy.

This might be possible: Exporting events to XML ([export fullcalendar to google calendar, ical, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686244/export-fullcalendar-to-google-calendar-ical-etc)) then XML to iCal, however both are rather dated tools so if there was a proper/working way that would be nice!

Comment: Nothing stopping you passing the events via the Google calendar API if you wanted to. You'd have to write the code to get the current event data (either from fullCalendar, or perhaps from whatever data store is used to populate the fullCalendar) and saving it to Google via the API

Comment: P.s. XML and iCal might be relatively old but that's not a reason to not use something - they both work and are both well supported. Old != Legacy

Comment: @ADyson hi Adyson, thanks for the comments. I was referring to the _tools_ that will convert the JSON to XML and XML to iCal, those might not work and are not well supported...

Comment: Yes that might well be the case. Although I suppose you could replace them. Personally I suspect you'd be better off with the API anyway. And potentially, depending on your exact scenario, better off doing it server side from your data source, rather than trying to export from fullCalendar. But I don't know your application structure so I can't be sure.